# android studio does not launch in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, android-studio, jvm

i am trying to install android studio in ubuntu, but when i execute the studio.sh, i get the following error:

```
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=350m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
```

i have java and jdk installed, my JAVA_HOME: `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/`

java -version output:

**java version "1.9.0-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.9.0-ea-b81)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 1.9.0-ea-b81, mixed mode)**

Comment: Which Android Studio? Eclipse or IntelliJ?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `java -version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem changing the `JAVA_HOME` value to:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_60
```

and i added it to `/etc/environment` file.

Answer (score 6):

You are using Java 9 and not Java 8 how your `JAVA_HOME` will make you credible. The option was abolished with Java 8 and even ignored at this time. With Java 9 is no longer the case, the start is aborted. Therefore use Java 8 via

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and/or remove the entries `MaxPermSize=350m` in the files

```
/opt/android-studio/bin/studio64.vmoptions
```

and

```
/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.vmoptions
```

Note, I have *Android Studio* installed in `/opt`

Comment: The first part of the answer didn't work, I only have one Java version installed (OpenJDK 9): `There is only one alternative in link group java. [...] Nothing to configure.`.

Answer (score 1):

Both java versions that you have listed are different.

Try

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Then on terminal go to the folder where you have extracted Android Studio folder and then run the following commands:

```
cd android-studio/bin
./studio.sh
```

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 16.10. Thank you!