# android studio VM error - Could not create Java Virtual Machine - A fatal exception has occured

Tags: android-studio

I tried installing android-studio on ubuntu, but it is giving me this weird error about unrecognized VM option

Here is a screenshot of the exact error

[image]

Comment: It always helps finding & fixing errors if you add the error-string as text and not only as image.

Comment: Sure, I will keep that in mind next time, its just I find image more appropriate in showing exactly what's happening, but i will post strings whenever possible.

Comment: The combination is the best deal for all users - as images aren't searchable.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, I will make sure both to have both next time. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android studio does not launch in ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/683618/android-studio-does-not-launch-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: I have 16.04, also this is the first time i am installing studio so there is no possibility of duplication.