# Android Studio not running _ Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, ubuntu-for-android

When I try to run the script ./studio.sh, to start Android Studio. I am getting the following error:

```
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=350m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Why am I getting this?

Comment: Have you installed Oracle JDK?

Comment: installed OpenJDK

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/683618/android-studio-does-not-launch-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: check the JAVA_HOME env!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got error

> Unrecognized option: -Xm4g  Error: Could not create the Java Virtual
>   Machine.  Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I solved this spelling error by editing home/.AndroidStudio3.0/studio64.vmoptions file.